# Как передать ссылку в класс?

Tags: php

Имеется два класса(см. ниже).
В каждом классе есть приватная переменная с данными и нужно в классе `A` создать экземпляр класса `B` и в конструктор передать данные, но чтоб не хранить данные в двух классах я хочу передать ссылку, но не выходит.

Ругается на строку `$q = new B(&$this->data);`:

> Fatal error: Call-time pass-by-reference has been removed

```
<?php

class B {
    private $data;

    public function __construct($data) {
        $this->data = $data;
    }
}

class A {
    private $data = "abc";

    public function b() {
        $q = new B(&$this->data);
    }
}

$a = new A();
$a->b();
```

Comment: И ещё почему я не могу добавить переносы строк?(в вопрос) в textarea они есть, отправляю, исчезают.

Comment: для добавления переноса, в конце предыдущей строки должно быть два пробела

Comment: [аналогичный вопрос на английском](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8971261/php-5-4-call-time-pass-by-reference-easy-fix-available) с ответом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ответ из аналогичного вопроса на английском](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8971261/php-5-4-call-time-pass-by-reference-easy-fix-available)
[Из документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.references.pass.php)

> **Замечание:** В вызове функции отсутствует знак ссылки - он есть только в определении функции. Этого достаточно для корректной передачи аргументов по ссылке. Начиная с PHP 5.3.0, вы можете получить предупреждение о том, что передача переменной по ссылке устарела, если используете & в foo(&$a);. Начиная с PHP 5.4.0 передача переменной по ссылке стала невозможна, поэтому использование этого приема приведет к фатальной ошибке.

Заменить

```
public function __construct($data) {
    $this->data = $data;
}
```

на

```
public function __construct(&$data) {
    $this->data = $data;
}
```

и вызывать

```
$q = new B($this->data);
```